# QuerySet basic methods typing

Tags: python, django, typing

Lets say i have a model `Event`, i want Event.objects.filter(blablabla) to return a QuerySet[Event], not just a QuerySet.

For this purpouse, i created a `Manager`. I need the manager in a separate file, since i have many Managers.
So an ideal thing to do would be something like

```
class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs) -> QuerySet[Event]:
        return super().filter(*args, **kwargs)
```

But i can't import the Event model, since it would be a circular import (Event.objects is the EventManager).

How can i provide type hints for the filter and get functions?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [TYPE_CHECKING](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) constant from the `typing` module. The constant will be `False` at run time, but assumed to be `True` by type checkers.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    import Event

class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs) -> QuerySet[Event]:
        return super().filter(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Well, it's not throwing an error anymore, but i still not get type hinting of any type.
get returns any and filter returns just QuerySet